# GridView only load one item when i start GridView Activity with Intent

Tags: android, gridview

When I opened my Activity(named MovieViewActivity.java or .class) with Intent and startActivity(), the activity load a gridView successfully, but the gridView only loads just first and unseen item which is vanished in bottom-out of screen.

At first, i thought it was a problem that related by memory leak, but when i scroll it up and down fastly, it loads their remain items as time goes.

I think a item is loaded when they vanished from screen, and i have know idea how to fix it.
Please help me so i can see all of items at first time that i load a view...

These are pictures about the problem.
(I erased picture and text for my privacy, blue square is picture(ImageView) and black one is text(TextView).)

[When I load activity, only first item only shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdJWK.png)

[After I scroll up and down fastly, every items are appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aorhy.png)

**And these are my codes.**

Part of MainActivity.java(load MovieViewActivity that has GridView)

```
@Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.movieGallery:
                showMovieGallery();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void showMovieGallery(){
        Intent videoIntent = new Intent(this, MovieViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(videoIntent);
    }
```

**Whole code of MovieViewActivity.java**

```
package SubViewClass;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.l.workspace.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MovieViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int[] imgIDs = new int[]{
            R.drawable.moviethumb0,
            R.drawable.moviethumb1,
            R.drawable.moviethumb2,
            R.drawable.moviethumb3,
            R.drawable.moviethumb4,
            R.drawable.moviethumb5,
            R.drawable.moviethumb6
    };
    private String[] imgTitles = new String[]{
            "소개 영상", "교육 후기", "다양한 놀이 활동",
            "영어로 놀아요", "영어 뮤지컬", "영어 요가", "영어 요리"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        GridView movieGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.movieGrid);

        movieAdapter thumbnailGridAdapter = new movieAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.griditem,
                imgIDs, imgTitles);
        movieGridView.setAdapter(thumbnailGridAdapter);

        movieGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                showVideoWithPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }
    public void showVideoWithPosition(int position){
        String movieName = "movie"+position;
        Intent videoIntent = new Intent(this, VideoViewActivity.class);
        videoIntent.putExtra("pos", movieName);
        startActivity(videoIntent);
    }

    /* 그리드뷰 아이템을 위한 Adapter클래스 */
    public class movieAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private int[] img = null;
        private String[] titles = null;
        private LayoutInflater inf;
        private int layout;

        public movieAdapter(Context _context,int _layout, int[] _imgIDs, String[] _titles){
            this.context = _context;
            this.layout = _layout;
            this.img = _imgIDs;
            this.titles = _titles;

            inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount(){
            return (img != null) ? img.length : 0;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position){
            return (img != null) ? img[position] : 0;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ImageView imgView;
            TextView txtView;

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inf.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            }else{

            /* 값을 지정할 이미지뷰와 텍스트뷰를 각각 griditem에서 가져옴. */
                imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImg);
                txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailTxt);

            /* GridView의 아이템을 구성할 ImageView와 TextView를 실제로 구성 */
                imgView.setImageResource(img[position]);
                txtView.setText(titles[position]);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout XML file of MovieViewActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/movieGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: problem is with Adapter code. Have you ever heard of View holder design pattern?

Comment: I found it just right now, and i change my code as you wrote to me.
And it works!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in MovieAdapter class.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int[] img = null;
    private String[] titles = null;
    private LayoutInflater inf;
    private int layout;

    public MovieAdapter (Context context, int[] img, String[] titles, int layout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.img = img;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.layout = layout;
        inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return (img != null) ? img.length : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.vault_item, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImg);
            holder.txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailTxt);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.imgView.setImageResource(img[i]);
        holder.txtView.setText(titles[i]);
        return view;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtView;
        private ImageView imgView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Work completely!! Thank you so much!